# Is there a way in python selenium to stop the script until a captcha is completed?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait

Basically i am triying to stop this script until the captcha is completed and then start again( i am using captcha automation)

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--profile-directory=Profile 9')
options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\dumpe\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\')
driver = uc.Chrome(executable_path='C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe', options=options)


driver.get("https://accounts.hcaptcha.com/demo")
driver.maximize_window()


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_any_elements_located((By.XPATH, "" )))

time.sleep(2)
driver.find_element(By.ID, 'hcaptcha-demo-submit').click()

time.sleep(10)

driver.close()
```

If anyone can help thank you for your time

i've tried to find the element that marks the captcha as completed but with no result : aria-checked="true" // also a bunch of other stuff like wait for the src attribute to change